# Creating an array length n * n, separating it into n groups, and adding numbers to it n times

Tags: java, beginner, programming-challenge, array

I am completing the CodingBat exercises for Java. [Here](http://codingbat.com/prob/p155405) is the one I have completed just now:

> Given `n > = 0`, create an array length `n * n` with the following pattern, shown here for `n = 3` :
>
> `{0, 0, 1,    0, 2, 1,    3, 2, 1}` (spaces added to show the 3 groups).

Here is my code:

```
    public int[] squareUp(int n){
    
    int[] ary = new int[n * n];
    int numberToInsert = 1;
    int count = 0;
    int target = n;
    
    //Guard condition for n = 1
    if (n == 1) {
        ary[0] = 1;
        return ary;
    }

    //Do the following n times
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        //Working from the end of the array backwards, insert the number
        //at the appropriate point
        for (int j = ary.length - numberToInsert; j > 0; j -= n) {
            ary[j] = numberToInsert;
            //The amount of times a number is inserted decreases each
            //iteration
            count++;
            if (count == target) {
                count = 0;
                target--;
                break;
            }
        }
        numberToInsert++;
    }
    return ary;
}
```

My questions are:

1. How would I implement this without the guard condition? The result without it is `0` because it doesn't get as far as the second `for` loop, as `numberToInsert` is already `1`. I tried to set this as `0`, and increment it later in the code, but I couldn't figure this out.
2. What alternative is there to the `count` and `target` system I implemented? Was this a good or bad way to achieve the outcome?
3. How else could the numbers be inserted? The method I used felt the most logical but I'm curious to see other methods.

Comment: Your program doesn't work as expected

Comment: @Mr.777 please clarify. If the program isn't working as intended, the question is off-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addressing into a 1d or 2d array is not a real problem for a square array

```
ary[i,j] = value;
```

can be written as

```
ary[i*n + j] = value
```

where n is the dimension.

The following passes the tests on CodingBat though there may be more elegant ways to approach it

```
public int[] squareUp(int n) {
    int[] result = new int[n*n]; 
    int zeroCount = n-1;
    for(int outer = 0; outer <n; outer++){
        for(int inner = 0; inner < n; inner++){
            result[(outer * n) + inner] = zeroCount > inner
                                            ? 0
                                            : (n-inner);
        }
        zeroCount--;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Perfect man. I still am trying to figure out the solution :P

Answer (score 2):

Look at the problem and think about the algorithm first (do not get distracted by limitations like 1D array instead of 2D).

For example:

> Fill each column with consecutive positive integers, starting from the last column. Additionally each consecutive column should contain one less row filled than previous (starting from the first row).

Then using @AlanT suggestion of how to convert 2D indexing into 1D one:

```
public int[] squareUp(int n) {
    int[] result = new int[n*n]; 
    int numberToInsert = 1;
    for(int column = n-1; column >= 0; column--){
        for(int row = n-1; row >= n-1-column; row--){
            result[(row * n) + column] = numberToInsert;
        }
        numberToInsert++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Explanation:

> Outer loop iterates columns, starting from the last one. Inner loop iterates rows, also starting from the last one, then uses column count to find stopping condition.

It also handles 0 and 1 array sizes. We also do not need to set 0 values as single-dimensional arrays of primitive values in Java will be set to default values on initialization.